# How to pipe Perforce command to "Find" CMD command?

Tags: command-line, windows-7, find, perforce

In Perforce CLI, the output of this command: `p4 login -s` is
 `Perforce password (P4PASSWD) invalid or unset.` if no user is logged in (see screenshot below).
When I pipe this command to *Find* command, I expect to get a blank line, but I still get the same line:
[image]

How can I pipe this command as I expect?

Comment: you're not "spending" your tags wisely. better to add tag that for your version of "MS Windows" (with many k followers) VS command-line-interface (1 follower). Good luck.

Comment: Are you asking about the difference between "find" and "findstr"? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/11/28/10372436.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Perforce password (P4PASSWD) invalid or unset.` message is output to STDERR, and `find` (and `findstr`, for that matter) only operate on STDOUT.  To solve this, use this:

```
p4 login -s 2>&1 | find "gg"
```

This will tie the output of STDERR (that is, stream 2) to STDOUT (stream 1).